# Sticky div doesn't work as it should

Tags: javascript, css, position, fixed, sticky

I'm trying to make a sticky div (sidebar, set to float:right). Now it applies position:fixed to the div, but when the div have position:fixed, the div gets moved to left, instead of it's original position which are to the right of the content.

I have created a jsfiddle to illustrate the exact issue: `jsfiddle:`  https://jsfiddle.net/h5o5z6jx/15/

Looking forward to read the replies!

Comment: add right:0px below top:0px and see if that is what you want

Comment: Setting your link inside of a code block is not the right way to get around the external link problem, add your code until then it is a great way to get down voted.

Comment: tried. that moves the div outside of the wrapper, so that isn't a good solution

Comment: And what is not working? what is the desired outcome? like this? https://jsfiddle.net/h5o5z6jx/11/

Comment: The desired outcome should be that the #sidebar-right stays in its position to the right of the #post-content. Just like it is before the #sidebar-right is given position:fixed.

Comment: Check this code and let me know if this is the desired outcome; https://jsfiddle.net/m1n2hr10/. If that's the case, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @RobertoS. almost yes, but everything need to be inside the width of wrapper. In your example the #sidebar-right goes outside the wrapper as you see. Almost there :)